How to find the correct "keystring" for an input keystroke in neovim?
I want to map the keystroke Ctrl + § to :Telescope oldfiles in neovim. I naively tried this:
vim.keymap.set('n', '<C-§>', ':Telescope oldfiles<CR>', {noremap = true, silent = true })

but this doesn't work. This is my keyboard:

The keys I want to map are marked in red. How would I now go about finding the correct "keymap string" I have to provide to nvim to recognise this combination?

This question is similar to: Map CTRL-& in vimrc. If you believe it’s different, please edit the question, make it clear how it’s different and/or how the answers on that question are not helpful for your problem.

@Friedrich It was helpful. I still don't quite understand if I can't rebind § in general since it is not in the ASCII spectrum? Is that really the case?

You can create a mapping for § but I don't think it's possible to create a mapping for <C-§>. You would test this with i<C-V><C-§> which will insert what Vim sees when you type <C-§>. Use ga with your cursor on the character to see the character code.

I wonder if the modifyOtherKeys feature could help here? What terminal are you using Neovim on? The feature is also supported on Neovim (https://neovim.io/doc/user/term.html#tui-modifyOtherKeys) though I'm not sure the overrides t_TI and t_TE are available there

@Fredrich It says <§> 167, Hex 00a7, Oct 247, Digr SE. I still don't understand. I mean § is in the extended ASCII set and has the value 167, so am I able to map character literals in the extended ascii set if they're single key presses, but not in combination with ctrl?

@filbran I use wezterm but sometimes with tmux in between. This indeed sounds like an interesting feature. However, I would need tmux to play along with it, I haven't looked into it so I don't know how much trouble awaits there...

If i<C-V><C-§> gives you the same character as i§, it means Vim cannot distinguish between the two. The actual character code and whether or not it's ASCII does not matter here.
